# Unable to get tabbing to work within dropdown (bootstrap)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, toggle

I'm trying to nest tabs within a dropdown and can't seem to get it to work correctly. I can get the tab to render on first click, but not when I go back and try to click on it again. I have created a bl.ocks http://bl.ocks.org/caseymm/6090448

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="pills-basic">
        <div class="tabbable">
            <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                Action
                    <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                <li><a href="#APS" data-toggle="tab">APS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#Cherokee" data-toggle="tab">Cherokee County</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#Clayton" data-toggle="tab">Clayton County</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Cobb" data-toggle="tab">Cobb County</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#DeKalb" data-toggle="tab">DeKalb County</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#Fayette" data-toggle="tab">Fayette County</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#Fulton" data-toggle="tab">Fulton County</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#Gwinnett" data-toggle="tab">Gwinnett County</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#Henry" data-toggle="tab">Henry County</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#Marietta" data-toggle="tab">Marietta City</a></li>

                        </ul>
                     </div>   

            <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div id="Home" class="tab-pane active">
                                        Some stuff.
                                    </div>
                <div id="Cherokee" class="tab-pane">
                                        <div class="rnkw-lists" data-rnkw-width="100%" data-rnkw-height="1376" data-rnkw-id="930926"></div>
                                        <a href="http://www.ranker.com/list/cherokee-county/atlantajournalconstitution" style="display:block; width:100%; padding-top:7px; font-size:12px; text-align:center;">Cherokee County</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="Cobb" class="tab-pane">
                                        <div class="rnkw-lists" data-rnkw-width="100%" data-rnkw-height="1510" data-rnkw-id="930947"></div>
                                        <a href="http://www.ranker.com/list/cobb-county/atlantajournalconstitution" style="display:block; width:100%; padding-top:7px; font-size:12px; text-align:center;">Cobb County</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="DeKalb" class="tab-pane">
                                        <div class="rnkw-lists" data-rnkw-width="100%" data-rnkw-height="1376" data-rnkw-id="930937"></div>
                                        <a href="http://www.ranker.com/list/dekalb-county/atlantajournalconstitution" style="display:block; width:100%; padding-top:7px; font-size:12px; text-align:center;">DeKalb County</a>
                </div>
                                    <div id="Gwinnett" class="tab-pane">
                                        <div class="rnkw-lists" data-rnkw-width="100%" data-rnkw-height="1309" data-rnkw-id="930945"></div>
                                        <a href="http://www.ranker.com/list/gwinnett-county/atlantajournalconstitution" style="display:block; width:100%; padding-top:7px; font-size:12px; text-align:center;">Gwinnett County</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="Marietta" class="tab-pane">
                                        <div class="rnkw-lists" data-rnkw-width="100%" data-rnkw-height="1242" data-rnkw-id="930911"></div>
                                        <a href="http://www.ranker.com/list/marietta-city/atlantajournalconstitution" style="display:block; width:100%; padding-top:7px; font-size:12px; text-align:center;">Marietta City</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="APS" class="tab-pane">
                                        <div class="rnkw-lists" data-rnkw-width="100%" data-rnkw-height="1912" data-rnkw-id="931127"></div>
                                        <a href="http://www.ranker.com/list/atlanta-public-schools-v1/atlantajournalconstitution" style="display:block; width:100%; padding-top:7px; font-size:12px; text-align:center;">Atlanta Public Schools</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="Fayette" class="tab-pane">
                                        <div class="rnkw-lists" data-rnkw-width="100%" data-rnkw-height="1108" data-rnkw-id="931534"></div>
                                        <a href="http://www.ranker.com/list/fayette-county-public-schools/atlantajournalconstitution" style="display:block; width:100%; padding-top:7px; font-size:12px; text-align:center;">Fayette County Public Schools</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="Henry" class="tab-pane">
                                        <div class="rnkw-lists" data-rnkw-width="100%" data-rnkw-height="1242" data-rnkw-id="931537"></div>
                                        <a href="http://www.ranker.com/list/henry-county-school-system/atlantajournalconstitution" style="display:block; width:100%; padding-top:7px; font-size:12px; text-align:center;">Henry County School System</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="Fulton" class="tab-pane">
                                        <div class="rnkw-lists" data-rnkw-width="100%" data-rnkw-height="907" data-rnkw-id="931543"></div>
                                        <a href="http://www.ranker.com/list/fulton-county/atlantajournalconstitution" style="display:block; width:100%; padding-top:7px; font-size:12px; text-align:center;">Fulton County</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="Clayton" class="tab-pane">
                                        <div class="rnkw-lists" data-rnkw-width="100%" data-rnkw-height="1711" data-rnkw-id="931546"></div>
                                        <a href="http://www.ranker.com/list/clayton-county-public-schools/atlantajournalconstitution" style="display:block; width:100%; padding-top:7px; font-size:12px; text-align:center;">Clayton County Public Schools</a>
                                    </div>
            </div><!-- /.tab-content -->


    </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something about your markup is not quite right, or maybe tab() and dropdown() are colliding, so that the active class isn't being removed from the list items.

In any case, you can hammer it into shape with this bit of jQuery:

```
$('#pills-basic a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
    $('#pills-basic .dropdown-menu li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/28qCe/5/